# How to get the value from a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here's my setup:

```
indices = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[2])
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([100000, 3], stddev=0.35))

def objective(indices, weights):
    idx1 = indices[0]; idx2 = indices[1] #extract two indices
    mask = np.zeros(weights.shape.as_list()[0]) #builds a mask for some tensor "weights"
    mask[idx1] = 1 # don't ask why I want to do this. I just do.
    mask[idx2] = 1
    obj = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(weights[idx1], weights[idx2]))
    return obj

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)

obj = objective(indices, weights)
trainer = optimizer.minimize(obj)


with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   sess.run([trainer, obj], feed_dict={indices=[100, 1000]})
```

So the point is that I have some tensor, and I take a slice of it which corresponds to an index in my `mask`. This index is a `tf.strided_slice`. I want to index my mask with `idx1` and `idx2`, as both evaluate to be ints.

But `idx1` and `idx2` are not ints but tensors, so the `obj = objective(indices, weights)` call leads to an error.

How can I get the code to work?

Comment: If you evaluate a tensor in a session, such as by calling eval(), you can index the NumPy array with its values. You haven't provided enough code to replicate your error, so it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: There's a bit more boilerplate overhead that I ignored. In particular, this is in an `objective` function that is passed into an optimizer (e.g. tf.GradientDescentOptimizer).

I'll update the code so it's clearer what my issue is and why your solution doesn't work.

Comment: OK I've updated the code to show where it breaks. Specifically, it breaks on my `objective` call, during the *graph definition*. The solution can't evolve running `eval()` in a session because the error occurs when I'm defining the graph, not when I'm executing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a combination of `tf.SparseTensor` and `tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense` to achieve what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

indices = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[2])
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 3], stddev=0.35))

def objective(indices, weights):
     idx1 = indices[0]; idx2 = indices[1] #extract two indices
     mask = np.zeros(weights.shape.as_list()[0]) #builds a mask for some tensor "weights"
     mask_ones = tf.SparseTensor(tf.reshape(indices, [-1,1]), [1, 1], mask.shape) # Stores the 1s used in the mask
     mask = mask + tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(mask_ones) # Set the mask
     obj = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(weights[idx1], weights[idx2]))
     return obj, mask

obj, mask = objective(indices, weights)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run([weights, obj, mask], feed_dict={indices:[0, 4]}))
```

`[array([[...]], dtype=float32), 0.0068909675, array([1., 0., 0., 0., 1.], dtype=int32)]`

Comment: This did work! I flagged it as correct because it corresponds to the question I asked, though it's not actually what I ended up using.